# issue with tomcat context setting in server.xml

Tags: java, tomcat7, ear

I am using tomcat 7.

When I set context different from war file name, everything works fine.

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<Context docBase="../webapps/abc.war" path="/def" reloadable="true" />
</Host>
```

But at tomcat startup I see two exploded folder abc and def.

Please help if anybody knows about this issue resolution.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you building this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Tomcat doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) (see "path" attribute):

> Even when statically defining a Context in server.xml, [the path] attribute
>   must not be set unless either the docBase is not located under the
>   Host's appBase or both deployOnStartup and autoDeploy are false. If
>   this rule is not followed, double deployment is likely to result.

This is a bit obscur, but my understanding is that you need to use an xml context file to achieve what you are trying to do. How to define a context config file is documented in the above link.

A simpler fix would be to just rename your war file to `def.war`.

Comment: Can you give example for xml. I don't know how to create xml file for context and map it to server.xml

Comment: It is documented in the link in my answer. But is there any reason why you want to have a context name different from the war file name? The simplest fix is to rename you war file to `def.war`.

Comment: That is company requirement. Project name is defined already in SVN and maven. So I can't change war name. But we have certain restrictions for not using war name as context name.

I am not getting from link how to apply xml config as separate <Conetxt>. I see that if we want to use default conext for multiple web app, then it is useful.